# My Ingress Nginx Controller and Load Balancer is not working on kubernetes cluster hosted at Digital Ocean

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, microservices, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

So I've been making a microservices app with Node Js, Docker, and Kubernetes. When i hosted the cluster at Digital Ocean. It did not go very well. The cluster is running but there is a problem with the Load Balancer and Ingress Nginx Controller so i cannot access the pods from outside the cluster.
This is my code for the Ingress and the Load Balancer

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: <my_domain>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/auth
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/jobscat
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-jobs-category-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/orders
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-orders-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/ratingreview
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-rating-review-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/searchrecommendation
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-search-recommendations-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ta-client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-enable-proxy-protocol: 'true'
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/do-loadbalancer-hostname: '<my_domain>'
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-2.0.3
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.32.0
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
```

And for some reason when i pushed it to the cluster it has an error that said

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "infra/k8s-prod/ingress-srv.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=29s": dial tcp 10.245.85.217:443: i/o timeout
```

Can anyone know what cause the problem? Thank you so much!!

This is the output when i run the command

```
kubectl get services

expiration-redis-srv            ClusterIP   10.245.221.247   <none>        6379/TCP            21h
kubernetes                      ClusterIP   10.245.0.1       <none>        443/TCP             47h
ta-auth-srv                     ClusterIP   10.245.187.196   <none>        3000/TCP            21h
ta-client-srv                   ClusterIP   10.245.228.194   <none>        3000/TCP            21h
ta-jobs-category-srv            ClusterIP   10.245.176.74    <none>        3000/TCP            21h
ta-nats-srv                     ClusterIP   10.245.173.206   <none>        4222/TCP,8222/TCP   21h
ta-orders-srv                   ClusterIP   10.245.213.151   <none>        3000/TCP            21h
ta-rating-review-srv            ClusterIP   10.245.212.168   <none>        3000/TCP            21h
ta-search-recommendations-srv   ClusterIP   10.245.0.230     <none>        3000/TCP            21h

kubectl get services --namespace ingress-nginx

ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.245.145.198   www.ta-vrilance.xyz   80:31618/TCP,443:32404/TCP   46h
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.245.85.217    <none>                443/TCP                      46h
```

This is the output when i run the command

```
kubectl get pods --namespace ingress-nginx

ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-74dhs   1/1     Running       18         5h10m
ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-gslw8   0/1     Terminating   1          5h29m
ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-tltzp   1/1     Terminating   0          22h
```

And this is the namespaces

```
default           Active   47h
ingress-nginx     Active   45h
kube-node-lease   Active   47h
kube-public       Active   47h
kube-system       Active   47h
```

This is the logs of ingress nginx controller pod

```
kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-74dhs
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.1.0
  Build:         cacbee86b6ccc45bde8ffc184521bed3022e7dee
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0114 05:35:41.919901       7 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0114 05:35:41.945407       7 main.go:223] "Creating API client" host="https://10.245.0.1:443"
I0114 05:35:42.036375       7 main.go:267] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="21" git="v1.21.5" state="clean" commit="aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691" platform="linux/amd64"
I0114 05:35:42.766004       7 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0114 05:35:42.872749       7 ssl.go:531] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0114 05:35:42.948206       7 nginx.go:255] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0114 05:35:42.990300       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"a5264e07-bc99-49db-9a0d-aedf8e92eb95", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"11874", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0114 05:35:44.581390       7 nginx.go:297] "Starting NGINX process"
I0114 05:35:44.704330       7 nginx.go:317] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0114 05:35:44.720237       7 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
I0114 05:35:44.864884       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0114 05:35:44.959938       7 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader
I0114 05:35:45.010881       7 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-74dhs"
I0114 05:35:45.636780       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0114 05:35:45.671253       7 controller.go:183] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0114 05:35:45.691014       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-74dhs", UID:"85da6a8f-8d93-4751-86aa-04e1a4142edd", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"332266", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
E0114 05:39:26.105536       7 leaderelection.go:330] error retrieving resource lock ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader: Get "https://10.245.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/configmaps/ingress-controller-leader": context deadline exceeded
I0114 05:39:29.925801       7 leaderelection.go:283] failed to renew lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader: timed out waiting for the condition
I0114 05:39:34.158509       7 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
W0114 05:42:28.287565       7 reflector.go:441] k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: watch of *v1.Secret ended with: an error on the server ("unable to decode an event from the watch stream: http2: client connection lost") has prevented the request from succeeding
W0114 05:42:28.302752       7 reflector.go:441] k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: watch of *v1.IngressClass ended with: an error on the server ("unable to decode an event from the watch stream: http2: client connection lost") has prevented the request from succeeding
W0114 05:42:28.312171       7 reflector.go:441] k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: watch of *v1.Service ended with: an error on the server ("unable to decode an event from the watch stream: http2: client connection lost") has prevented the request from succeeding
W0114 05:42:28.494491       7 reflector.go:441] k8s.io/client-go@v0.22.2/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: watch of *v1.Ingress ended with: an error on the server ("unable to decode an event from the watch stream: http2: client connection lost") has prevented the request from succeeding
I0114 05:42:33.108017       7 main.go:169] "Received SIGTERM, shutting down"
I0114 05:42:33.476882       7 nginx.go:373] "Shutting down controller queues"
```

Comment: can you post the output of `kubectl get services,pods --namespace ingress-nginx` to your question.

Comment: yes, i already edited my question. thanks for answering! @gohm'c

Comment: You have not posted the correct output for ingress-nginx namespace, can you post the output of `kubectl get services,pods --namespace ingress-nginx`

Comment: oh im sorry, i've added the output and i hope that's right. Thank youu @gohm'c

Comment: The output suggest your ingress-nginx controller is not running properly, that's why you are getting `Error from server (InternalError): error when creating...`. You need to see what's wrong in the ingress-nginx controller logs first.

Comment: i've added the logs @gohm'c

Comment: This k8s cluster was upgraded recently?

Comment: no, i dont think so.

Comment: `Get "https://10.245.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/configmaps/ingress-controller-leader": context deadline exceeded` - it has problem trying to communicate with the api-server

Comment: is it because i mention 2 ports in the load balancer?

Comment: How did you install Nginx Ingress?

Comment: i run the command from the NGINX Ingress website. Then i push my ingress controller on my github to make the pod on the cluster. I used github workflow to automaticaly create the pod on the digital ocean kubernetes cluster